# Retrieve list from database using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I have a database named `findall_db` with one table named `person`... I have manually added some values to this table and would like to retrieve them using Spring Boot. This is what I have but I keep getting this error in my controller: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<PersonInfo> to List<PersonInfo>`

The Entity Class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class PersonInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PERSON_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "PERSON_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PERSON_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ssn")
    private String socialSecurityNumber;

    private String name;

    public PersonInfo() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonInfo [id=" + id + ", socialSecurityNumber=" + socialSecurityNumber + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Repository class is:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonInfoRepository extends CrudRepository < PersonInfo, Long > {

 }
```

Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonInfoRepository personRepo;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/people")
    public List printPersonInfo() {

        List < PersonInfo > people = personRepo.findAll();

        System.out.println(people.toString());

        return people;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`CrudRepository#findAll`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAll--) returns an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and not a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). So, you either <sup>(1)</sup> change the method signature to return an `Iterable` as well or you  <sup>(2)</sup> copy the elements to a `List` and return it.

(1) Return `Iterable`:

```
public Iterable<PersonInfo> printPersonInfo() {
    return personRepo.findAll();
}
```

(2) Copy the elements to a `List` and return the list.

```
public List<PersonInfo> printPersonInfo() {
    List<PersonInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    personRepo.findAll().forEach(list::add);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was suggested by the first answer and it works..thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<PersonInfo> printPersonInfo() {    
       List<PersonInfo> people = personRepo.findAll()
                                           .stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
       System.out.println(people.toString());
       return people ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your repository extend [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) instead of [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

```
@Repository
public interface PersonInfoRepository extends JpaRepository < PersonInfo, Long > {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
PersonInfoRepository personRepo;

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/people")
public List printPersonInfo() {

    List < PersonInfo > people = personRepo.findAll();

    System.out.println(people.toString());

    return people;
}
```

in this part of code you didnt initialized (casted is better) your controller variable

you can easy cast it with `List<PersonInfo>` after `people =`